# What causes 'kernel panic' in Kali Linux running on VMware Workstation Player?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb, kernel-panic, vmware-workstation

I installed *Kali Linux 2020.2* as a virtual machine in *VMware Workstation Player* on *Windows 10 Home* as the host.

**uname -mrsvo :**

```
Linux 5.5.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.5.17-1kali1 (2020-04-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As expected, my internal wireless network adapter did not support monitor mode nor packet injection, so I attached an external one which does. Pentesting functions work as intended using this external adapter.

The external adapter is a brandless Chinese-made one, that worked fine when it was the only adapter in my previous old PC.
The MAC address lookup claims it's a *Liteon* device.

**lsusb :**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
```

Now, whenever I try to use the web browser the VM is halted with the threatening message :
"*The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.*"
There are no issues with the VM when the external adapter is disconnected.
I have to disconnect the external adapter and restart the VM before I can use the web browser normally without issues.
This external adapter is only used for pentesting purposes, not to connect to the Internet.

BTW, using both adapters from *Windows 10 Home* also caused the dreaded BSOD, so I don't use the external adapter in *Windows* anymore, don't need it there anyway.

What's wrong with this setup ?

Comment: Can you trigger the panic when the network adapter is disconnected? If not, it's likely to be the driver causing the issue, and you should (a) [edit] your question to tell us what make/model it is along with `uname -mrsvo` and the relevant line of output of `lsusb`, (b) search around generally for issues with said adapter running under a Linux kernel.